# How to add multiple button in 1 line (css)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't add multiple button in 1 line although I tried many times.

This is my code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

<div class="g-follow" data-annotation="none" data-height="24" data-href="//plus.google.com/u/0/105096562375742" data-rel="publisher"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/twittert" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en" data-size="large">Follow @twitter</a>
```

Please help me ! Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Div elements are always **block level elements**. This means that they will display on their own lines. To make them display as **inline elements**, you will need to set the css property `display: inline;` (or `inline-block` depending on the specific behavior you want) on the divs in question.

Comment: Can you tell more detail, please ?

Comment: I don't really know what more detail there is -- in your CSS, you need to apply `display: inline;` to each of the buttons. I'd do that by giving them all an extra class `button` and applying the rule to that class, but you could refer to them all by their classes or even IDs --`display` is the property you need to change.

Comment: Yes ! It worked. Can you tell me how to create spaces between buttons, please ? My buttons is sequential. Thanks !

Comment: I would recommend using the `margin` or `padding` css properties to set the spacing in between.